# Hide Div Container in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide a DIV after a certain amount of seconds using CSS3. So far I have some jQuery code that hides the div after 7 seconds. Is it possible to do this in CSS?

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/LmHTR/2/)

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> 
    div
    {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    animation:myfirst 7s; /* IE 10+ */
    -moz-animation:myfirst 7s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:myfirst 7s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation:myfirst 7s; /* Opera */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;   
    }

    @keyframes myfirst
    {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    99%{opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity:0;}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes myfirst /* Firefox */
    {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    99%{opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity:0;}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
    {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    99%{opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity:0;}
    }

    @-o-keyframes myfirst /* Opera */
    {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    99%{opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity:0;}
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div>hello world</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: IE10 [supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453858.aspx) `@keyframes`.

Comment: this starts fading the div right away over a 7s duration, I think @James is looking to wait 7s then fade it out quickly.

Comment: @mdmullinax  just add 99% in the keyframe block

Comment: @Evan Your code still says it doesn't work in IE. Again, IE supports animations and keyframes.

Comment: @JonathanSampson sorry, I corrected it, but then I was doing some formatting and I copied and pasted my previous code...

Answer (score 3):

Set your keyframe, its duration, its delay before starting, and instruct it to retain its last values:

```
#foo { 
    animation: fademe 1s 7s forwards
}

@keyframes fademe { 
    to { opacity: 0 } 
}
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/joe/pen/mkwxi

This code example doesn't contain any required vendor prefixes. To run as-is, you should consider using Prefix-free: http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of the [animation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/) properties, specifically, `animation-name`, `animation-duration`, `animation-iteration-count`, `animation-delay`, and `animation-fill-mode`

You'll also need `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-o-`, and for consistency `-ms-` (though IE10 I believe works without vendor prefixes) for each `animation` style

```
animation-name:bubbly; /* name of keyframe animation (note @keyframe blocks need vendor prefixes also (atm) */
animation-duration:0.9s; /* how long the keyframe takes to run */
animation-iteration-count:1; /* how many times to run the keyframe */
animation-delay:7s; /* how long before the keyframe starts running */
animation-fill-mode:forwards; /* which styles to apply once the keyframe is done */
```

Or summed up in one `animation` statement

```
animation: bubbly 0.9s 7s 1 forwards;
```

And the keyframe

```
@keyframes bubbly {
  from {opacity:1;}
  to {opacity: 0;} 
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LmHTR/24/) (with vendor prefixes)